# Where can I get the source code of KDE's Folder View plasmoid?

Tags: kde, source-code, screenlets, plasma

I want to have a look at the code of the `FolderView` [plasmoid](http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma#Folder_Views) (which is the thing I miss most from KDE) to see if it is in any way similar to the `FolderView` [screenlet](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Folderview+Screenlet?content=102890&PHPSESSID=9f268f9704d741fc55257a44e21d9440).

The screenlet is so buggy right now it's virtually useless (it hasn't been updated in two years) and maybe when I have the time, in like 20 years, I could try to debug/improve it to have it behave more like KDE's **far superior** plasmoid.

Comment: Plasmoids are made with KDE's Plasma technology, based on Qt. So I'm 99.9% sure they have nothing common at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can browse the source code of Folder View plasmoid at
[KDE Projects](https://projects.kde.org/) → KDE / KDE Base Apps → Repository → root/plasma/applets/[**folderview**](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kde-baseapps/repository/revisions/master/show/plasma/applets/folderview)
or checkout the KDE Base Apps repository with `git clone git://anongit.kde.org/kde-baseapps`.

Comment: Wow, that is a **lot** of code. Thanks @BlaXpirit!